# Foreign Key value in child table on MariaDB shows duplicated value from parent table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I was just started creating some database. Very basic, two tables only, and I add this one foreign key, JUST LIKE most tutorials.

Here's what happened, step by step...

I created table UserRole:

```
IDUserRole int not null auto_increment,
UserRole varchar(8) not null,
primary key (IDUserRole),
index (UserRole)
```

then I added some data:

```
IDUserRole = 1, UserRole = "ADMIN"
IDUserRole = 2, UserRole = "UKM"
```

then I created another table called UserName:

```
IDUserName int not null auto_increment,
UserName varchar(50) not null,
UserRole varchar(8) not null,
primary key (IDUserName),
index (UserRole),
constraint fkfk foreign key (UserRole) references userrole (UserRole)
on delete restrict on update cascade
```

then I tried to input a value in the UserRole field, on UserName table. Something's funny came up when I click on the value:

[image: screenshot]

It shows not only one, but TWO values separated with '-', TWICE... Like this for the simpler picture:

ADMIN-ADMIN
UKM-UKM

ADMIN-ADMIN
UKM-UKM

In some cases, it's gone like this:

[image: screenshot2]

ADMIN-Lam Johannes
UKM-blablabla
SENDER-blablabla
SELLER-blbablba
...

Lam Johannes-ADMIN
blablabla-UKM
blablabla-SENDER
blbablba-SELLER

So anyone please, why did this occur? And how can I fix it?
 Oh, by the way I use XAMPP, and open the database with phyMyAdmin

Comment: It's a buglet in phpMyAdmin though I can't find an open problem for it. It's been like that for a very long time.

Comment: Did you have FKs disabled at any time?  Is there a space (perhaps at the end) in either of those dup values?